# How to apply the style to custom data attribute?

Tags: html, css

As an exmple I have this code with an data-append attribute that should be executed for the tablets and desktops. How shoud I apply the style for this peace of html-code: in the main (parent html stylesheet) with implementing ID for containers or in the child html or try to style it inline ?

```css
body {
 background: #fff;
 font-family: 'Verdana', sans;
  font-size:16px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
}

.skip{
 clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
 margin: -1px; 
 overflow:hidden;
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
  top: -1px; 
  left: -1px;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class='skip'>Exploration of css rules of the hidden submenu</h1>
    <nav nav ul>
      <h2 class='skip'>Menu with one submenu</h2>
         <ul>
           <!--A as a custom data attribute for screens with width more than 767px-->
           <li id='customData' data-append='/a-plus.html' data-media='(min-width:768px)'>
            <a href='/a'>A</a></li>
           <li><a href='/b'>B</a><li>    <!--B-->
           <li><a href='/c'>C</a></li>   <!--C-->
          </ul>
     </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I understood you correctly.

If you want to style an element that has the attribute `data-append`, simply use and [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target it in your CSS.

Below I'm using `[data-append]` as my selector, which means **any** element that has the attribute `data-append` will get the styling. If you wanted to limit it to `li` then use `li[data-append] {}`.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.skip {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

[data-append] {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='skip'>Exploration of css rules of the hidden submenu</h1>

<nav>

  <h2 class='skip'>Menu with one submenu</h2>

  <ul>
    <!--A as a custom data attribute for screens with width more than 767px-->
    <li id='customData' data-append='/a-plus.html' data-media='(min-width:768px)'>
      <a href='/a'>A</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='/b'>B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='/c'>C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @hungerstar. But what if the data from another html peace is auet complex (it has its own submenu with divs, figures, images and so on). How to style in this case?

Comment: @o_k_s_a_n_a please provide an example of this HTML and how you intend to style it. I'm assuming that you're asking how to style `data-append` elements differently if they're nested.

Comment: Sorry @hungerstar, I asked about the principle how the peace of added html-file as data-append element should be styled. Does it should have its own stylesheet if it's very complex?

Comment: @o_k_s_a_n_a again, please provide an example of the HTML and CSS that you have in mind. I don't know why you would ever need a separate stylesheet just to style elements that have `data-append` on them. If you're talking about using a stylesheet (CSS file) vs inline CSS (`style=""`), then use a stylesheet. Basically, avoid inline CSS whenever you can. Over time you will learn when it is okay to use, which is only about `0.01%` of the time. The other `99.99%` you're gong to use a separate file for your CSS. Does that answer your question?

Comment: There is a simpified

Comment: Thanks for your pations, @hungerstar. I really appriciate any your help. There is a simpified example of peace of added navigation as data attribute, but in the reality it should be much more compicated. So, if I will create this html file with its own stylesheert how I must to avoid the possible style conflicts with the page where it should be integrated (I understand that it's obviously recommended to avoid inline styling as usually I use it only for the svg elements)? https://jsbin.com/vihidovoqo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @o_k_s_a_n_a you have issues with the markup in your jsbin. There's elements between elements that shouldn't be there, i.e. You can't place a `<div>` between a `<ul>` and a `<li>`. Plus it looks like there's opening tags where there should be closing tags. Do you know CSS very well. It's not hard to _"scope"_ CSS selectors. If you want the styles for `[data-append]{}` to only apply to the `<nav>` then use `nav [data-append] {}`.

Comment: I've corrected https://jsbin.com/qocevevame/edit?html,css,output
Do I understood well that you recomend that if I wand to scope any tad id, css that I should use for exmple:
ul li [data-append]{} 
in the main stylesheet, and not attached as link to html of custom data file (it was my main goal of this question). And if so, wouldn't it impact on speed of mobile version of the web-aplication as I will include all data to unique css file?
Thanks a lot in any case @hungerstar !

Comment: @o_k_s_a_n_a let's take it one step at a time. **First** lets make sure you understand scope and that it is addressing your issue of how to prevent some elements from being styled a certain way. Take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5mxtuzd/) that shows and example of scoping with CSS. Do you understand this and does it address your styling concerns?

Comment: yes, I do understand now how to scope, it's very clean @hungerstar

Comment: @o_k_s_a_n_a okay, now where to place your CSS for the `data-append` elements? How many lines of CSS do you plan to write to style the `data-append` elements? 1,000 lines? I doubt it. Probably more like 10-50 lines. The few lines you're going to add to style those elements isn't going to make a huge impact on how long it will take to download the CSS file. Place the CSS in your external stylesheet with the rest of your sites CSS. Placcing it in the external stylesheet allows the browser to cache (store) it for future use so it doesn't need to re-download the file the next time the user visits.

Comment: Thanks for this journey @hungerstar, I understand now all and completely agree